# Splitting a string using specified delimiters, and replacing some portions

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have content like this `Go to {#www.google.com##Google#}`, and I want to use this as a clickable link, as shown below:

`Go to <a href="www.google.com" title="Google">Google</a>`.

my try: `var splCharData = splCharData.split(/[\{#\#}]/g);`

Comment: what regular expression did you try already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finding the regular expression is actually the easy part. It's easy to forget that even in JavaScript you should protect against XSS vulnerabilities.

One way to make sure the values are properly escaped is to actually create an anchor and then query its `outerHTML` property:

```
var str = 'Go to {#www.google.com##Google#}',
    m = /\{#([^#]+)##([^#]+)#\}/g;

alert(str.replace(m, function($0, $1, $2) {
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href = 'http://' + $1;
  a.title = $2;
  a.textContent = $2;

  return a.outerHTML;
}));
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/ipukew/1/)

Alternatively, you could use a strings-only approach and manually escape whatever you push inside attributes.

```
var str = 'Go to {#www.google.com##Google#}',
    m = /\{#([^#]+)##([^#]+)#\}/g,
    htmlspecialchars = function(str) {
      return str
        .replace('<', '&lt;')
        .replace('&', '&amp;')
        .replace('>', '&gt;')
        .replace('"', '&quot;');
    };

alert(str.replace(m, function($0, $1, $2) {
  return '<a href="' + 
    htmlspecialchars('http://' + $1) +
    '" title="' +
    htmlspecialchars($2) + 
    '">' + 
    htmlspecialchars($2) +
    '</a>';
}));
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/ipukew/4/)

Comment: Assuming it's going into a document, you might as well just return the node to be inserted and skip the `outerHTML` part, no? (idk who's downvoting stuff, it's not me)

Comment: @DaggNabbit Adding the nodes into the document is actually harder, because you have to create text nodes of the things that weren't matched ... updated the answer with a string approach though :)

Comment: Ah, good point. Don't forget to escape `&`! Also I think `>` doesn't need to be escaped, strictly speaking.

Comment: @DaggNabbit Ah yes, I was wondering for a while why `&` strictly needs to be escaped (I don't think it's truly XSS), but then I remembered :)

Answer (score 1):

Find for : `\{#([^#]+)##([^#]+)#\}`

Replace with :`<a href="$1" title="$2">$2</a>`